# SipDemo manager is always null in device SamSung SII android SIP API

Tags: android, sip

Recently, I'm trying to use `SIP API` in android and for many times searching, I find out SipDemo (the `sample project` of `android-10`). I just import the project in eclipse. However, when I look for detail in this project (by `Log.e(...)`), I find out that `SipManager manager` is always `null` even right after this line: `manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);`. Therefore, no matter what I register to the Sip provider, I can't get it work! Any one has the same problem? Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Edited:

if I use the  [link here](http://xilard.hu/), I can get my emulator work with `register`, `call` and `receive` a call. However, with my device, SamSung SII, it doesn't work!! Is this because of my device or something wrong with the basic API?!

Comment: do you have internet and android.permission.USE_SIP in your uses permision in manifest.

Comment: of course, yes! This is `SipDemo sample project` of  `android-10`

Comment: Ru running in device or emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Not all Android-powered devices support VOIP calls using SIP. You should always call `isVoipSupported()` to verify that the device supports VOIP calling and `isApiSupported()` to verify that the device supports the SIP APIs.

Comment: I called 2 fucntions that U suggest and all I got are 'false`! So can't I use VOIP for this device? Is that `SIP API` not portable?

Comment: The decision to support the SIP API is left to the manufacturer. For some reason, he may choose not to support it even if you have Android 2.3.4  or +.

Comment: You mean that I have to change another device in order to test `SipDemo`?